# Django query which calculate most active post by like and dislike, and by each category

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I want to calculate most popular post by each category, but i have this error  **DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend**.

after i use **PostgreSql**, but I also had a error. annotation and distinct together did not work.

model -->

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name=_("კატეგორია"))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_("მომხმარებელი")
    )
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name=_("სათაური"))
    body = models.TextField(verbose_name=_("ტექსტი"))
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_("ფოტო"))
    link = models.URLField(
        max_length=400,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        validators=[RequireHttpOrHttpsUrl()],
        verbose_name=_("ლინკი"),
    )
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    send_notification = models.BooleanField(
        default=True, verbose_name=_("გავაგზავნოთ შეტყობინება?")
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class LikeDislike(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_("მომხმარებელი")
    )
    question = models.ForeignKey(
        Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_("კითხვა")
    )
    point = models.BooleanField()
    time = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question.title
```

view ->

```
class CountLikeByCategory(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CountLikeByCategorySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        query=Question.objects.values_list(
            'category__title','title'
        ).annotate(
            l=Count('likedislike',filter=Q(likedislike__point=1)),
            d=Count('likedislike',filter=Q(likedislike__point=0)),
            total=F('l')+F('d'),
        ).order_by('category', '-total').distinct('category')
        return query
```

who can help me?

i wan correct query

Comment: What error are you getting since using PostgreSQL?

Comment: @ViktorMironov Django: NotImplementedError: annotate() + distinct(fields) is not implemented

Comment: @ViktorMironov I use total=Max('total') in filter but did not work

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
        query=Question.objects.values_list(
            'category','category__title','title'
        ).annotate(
            l=Count('likedislike',filter=Q(likedislike__point=1)),
            d=Count('likedislike',filter=Q(likedislike__point=0)),
            total=F('l')+F('d'),
        ).order_by('category', '-total').distinct('category')
        return query
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. Your answer would be much more valuable to us if you added an explanation about what your code does and why it helps the OP

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment, in base question he used distinct by 'category' but 'category' is not in his values_list fields.
@SimasJoneliunas